# ASP.Net fileupload control rotates PDF file when uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, file-upload

While uploading any PDF file through the ASP.Net file upload control, some of the PDF pages are getting rotated automatically. Why this is happening? How can I avoid this rotation?

Comment: you want to disable the processing icon right??

Comment: No! The PDF page content is rotated at 180 degree after uploading. I want to avoid this rotation.

Comment: Please share your code